# Don't Extend Lines on React Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a problem on the `lines` between the `OR`. I need it not to be extended to its beginning/end.

Please see codesandbox here **[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/box-circle-styled-components-forked-z4yn3?file=/src/Form.js)**

**EXPECTED OUPUT**

[image]

**CODE**

```
const OR = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
  color: #5C5C5C;
  font-size: 14px;
  &:before, &:after {
    content: "";
    flex: 1 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #A1A1A1;
    margin: auto;
  }
  &:before {
    margin-right: 10px
  }
  &:after {
    margin-left: 10px
  }
}
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 &:before, &:after {
    content: "";
    width:30%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #A1A1A1;
    margin: auto;
```

Put this instead of the border.

Answer (score 1):

just change your `OR` component like this

```
const OR = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width:50%; // Add
  flex-direction: row;  
  color: #5C5C5C;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto; // Add
  &:before, &:after {
    content: "";
    flex: 1 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #A1A1A1;
    margin: auto;
  }
  &:before {
    margin-right: 10px
  }
  &:after {
    margin-left: 10px
  }
}
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set max-width for the pseudo elements ::before and ::after

```
const OR = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
  color: #5C5C5C;
  font-size: 14px;
  &:before, &:after {
    content: "";
    flex: 1 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #A1A1A1;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 30%;
  }
  &:before {
    margin-right: 10px
  }
  &:after {
    margin-left: 10px
  }
}`
```

Updated [link](https://pht6g.csb.app/)